# Is it possible to implement swscanf_s via swscanf?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am building a project on android, this project uses many swscanf_s, but android doesn't support swscanf_s, so I wonder is it possible to implement swscanf_s via swscanf?

note: the difference between swscanf_s and swscanf http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwscanf

> swscanf_s: %c, %s, and %[ conversion specifiers each expect two arguments

I have thought about it for a long time

1. use regular expression to parse the format string, the problem is that android doesn't support vswscanf either.
2. implement swscanf_s as a variadic template. we can assume all buffer size arguments are integral and other arguments are pointer, so if I can extract all pointer arguments then pass them to swscanf, it will work. unfortunately, I also failed.

Do you have any idea? I hope the implementation wouldn't be too complicated or it will be lower-cost to replace all swscanf_s.

Other solution will also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: *"unfortunately, I also failed."* - people usually post their failures, with full details of the the error messages or behaviours that they're stumped by - can save other people from starting from scratch, or let someone quickly help you along....

Comment: right, I just failed to implement such a template. My idea seems practical but the implementation is hard or even impossible. I wonder if my idea is really practical.

Comment: Not 100% sure it's viable, but have you considered whether you can modify the format string - e.g. changing `%s`  to `%*s` which expects a buffer length argument then buffer address, which is - if I understand correctly - what the `_s` version expects for `%s`?  There are examples of compile time string processing out there now that `constexpr` is available, or you could do it at runtime.

Comment: replacing all those swscanf_s's with proper c++ string handling would be time well spent.